# Viewer.JS File Name from Title Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, attr

I'm using viewer.js (http://viewerjs.org/) to view pdf's on a website, and I want to pull the attribute "title" from the iframe code to title the document.

At the moment the code is as follows

`<iframe id="viewer" src = "/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>`

and I want to be able to do this

`<iframe id="viewer" src = "/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen title="Document Title"></iframe>`

I know the bit of code in the js file I need to edit is as follows

```
document.getElementById("documentName").innerHTML=document.title
```

and I tried the following but with no luck

```
document.getElementById("documentName").innerHTML=document.attr('title')
```

I'm just not sure how to get the attribute.

The full source code for viewer.js can be viewed at http://viewerjs.org/ViewerJS/viewer.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out how to do it, it just needed to be as follows

`document.getElementById("documentName").innerHTML=window.frameElement.title`

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to pass the `title` parameter like this:

```
<iframe src="/ViewerJS/?title=My PDF Title#../demo/ohm2013.odp"></iframe>
```

Just notice that it **must** be placed *before* the document's URL.